# ORing multiple NOT fields in java

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following expression in java:

```
     String name = request.getParameter("name");
     String email = request.getParameter("email");
     String password = request.getParameter("password");

     if (!name || !email || !password) {
         model.addAttribute("error", "Enter all fields please!");
     }
    return "register";
```

However, I get an error that complains about the `!` operator. What would be the correct way to do the above `if` statement?

Comment: The above code is correct Java if `name`, `email`, and `password` are all **`boolean`** variables. Since they are probably `String` variables, what did you expect the code to do? Java is not JavaScript, and the `!` operator only works on boolean values.

Comment: @Andreas please see updated code: my guess is it has to do with checking the string value.

Comment: `!name` makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to do with that? You can only negate boolean expressions, not Strings

Comment: You *guess* is it "has to do with string value"????? Didn't you write the code? What did *you* intend the code to do? *Why* did you think `!` on a `String` is valid?

Comment: `if(name!=null && !name.isEmpty()){`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third party library, you can use StringUtils class as below:

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) || StringUtils.isEmpty(email) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
     model.addAttribute("error", "Enter all fields please!");
 }
```

Details available at : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score -2):

If using a string, checking whether it is empty or not can be done as follows:

```
 if (name.isEmpty()|| email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
     model.addAttribute("error", "Enter all fields please!");
 }
```

To check whether it is empty or null, you can do the following:

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

 if (StringUtils.isEmpty(name)|| StringUtils.isEmpty(email) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
     model.addAttribute("error", "Enter all fields please!");
 }
```

Comment: might also need to check for `null` if the values are absent

Comment: You’ve answered your own question despite apparently not knowing what was going on. You should add a `!=null` check too.

Comment: [`StringUtils.isEmpty(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String)) from Apache commons library is useful for this or its counterpart `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String)`.

Comment: Providing a self answer to such a common question is not really liked here. You *should* know that according to your reputation...